# Create ggplots with the same scale in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, bar-chart

I'd like to do the following in R: I have 2 datasets (one consisting of 4, the other of 3 values) and I'd like to plot them with ggplot2 as bar charts (separately). However, I'd like to use the same scale for the both, i.e.: if the minimum value of dataset #1 is 0.2 and 0.4 of dataset #2, then I want to use 0.2 for both. Same applies for the maximum values (choosing the greater there).

So, basically, I want to make the 2 plots comparable. Of course, would be great to apply the common scale for coloring the bars, as well. Now, I'm using `colorRampPalette` and applying it in the `scale_fill_gradient2` property.

A MWE provided below:

```
library("ggplot2")
val <- c(0.2, 0.35, 0.5, 0.65)
labels <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

LtoM <-colorRampPalette(c('green', 'yellow'))

df <- data.frame(val)
bar <- ggplot(data = df,
              aes(x = factor(labels),
                  y = val,
                  fill = val)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low=LtoM(100), mid='snow3', 
                       high=LtoM(100), space='Lab') +
  geom_text(aes(label = val), vjust = -1, fontface = "bold") +
  labs(title = "Title", y = "Value", x = "Methods") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
print(bar)
```

Given the code above, and another dataset like `c(0.4, 0.8, 1.2)` with labels `c('E', 'F', 'G')`, how to adjust the code to create 2 different and separated plots (saved into PNGs finally, i.e.) but use the common (`0.2 to 1.2`) scale for both the heights of bars and their colors (so moving the images exactly next to each other indicates that the bars with the same height but belonging to different images appear in the same way and their colors are the same)?

Comment: You can try something like `min(min(dataset1),  min(dataset2))` as your first `ylim()` argument.

Comment: Thank you so much, tried it and almost works in the same way like the answer below (except adjusting).

Comment: You can set the `limits` in `scale_fill_gradient2` to keep the fill scale the same between plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a mix of the `breaks` argument in `scale_y_continuous` to ensure that we have consistent axis ticks, then use `coord_cartesian` to ensure that we force both plots to have the same y-axis range.

```
df1 <- data.frame(val = c(0.2, 0.35, 0.5, 0.65), labels = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
df2 <- data.frame(val = c(0.4, 0.8, 1.2), labels = c('E', 'F', 'G'))

g_plot <- function(df) {
    ggplot(data = df,
          aes(x = factor(labels),
              y = val,
              fill = val)) +
        geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
        scale_fill_gradient2(low=LtoM(100), mid='snow3', 
                     high=LtoM(100), space='Lab') +
        geom_text(aes(label = val), vjust = -1, fontface = "bold") +
        scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1.2, 0.2)) + 
        coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1.2)) + 
        labs(title = "Title", y = "Value", x = "Methods") +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
}

bar1 <- g_plot(df1);
bar2 <- g_plot(df2);
gridExtra::grid.arrange(bar1, bar2, ncol = 2);
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Impressive answer, thank you so much. :) The only thing that hasn't been resolved is the coloring. Any idea for the common color-scale (0.65 and 1.2 definitely have the same yellow color but the letter should be at least orange, or red)?

Comment: Managed to solve the coloring on my own (providing different coloring arguments per plot to the `scale_fill_gradient2` property). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You actually dont need to use coord_cartesian. You can just use the limits argument in scale_y_continuous, like this:

scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1.2), breaks = seq(0, 1.2, 0.2))